# Javascript how to convert sstring to date

Tags: javascript, date

I need to write a script to update a time. I want to make it increase by 20 seconds so

```
"Jun 23, 2011 12:00 AM"
```

becomes

```
"Jun 23, 2011 12:20 AM"
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var seconds = 1000; // 1 second = 1000 milliseconds

var originalDate = Date.parse("Jun 23, 2011 12:00 AM");

var newDate = new Date(originalDate + 2 * seconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to manipulate dates is with the Date.js library available at http://datejs.com/. Then it would be:

```
var d = Date.parse("Jun 23, 2011 12:00 AM").add(20).seconds();
```

Or if d is already set to a date, you could simply do:

```
var d = new Date(d.getTime() + 20000);
```